# Reedy model structure, simplicial sets and model categories

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff, model-categories

I have two questions, the first one is just wether the following statement is true or not? Is there a reference for this?

[image]

The second one is much more open, it's basically what restricitions do we have to put on a cosimplicial object $U:\Delta \rightarrow C$ such that the functor $$F_U:C \rightarrow \text{s}\textbf{Set}$$ given by $$F_U(c)_n = \operatorname{Hom}(U_n,c)$$ preserves weak equivalences and/or cofibrations between sufficiently nice objects?

Comment: I've deleted the "model-theory" tag - it doesn't refer to model categories, but rather [a subfield of mathematical logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_theory) (one of categorical interest, certainly, but not relevant to model categories as far as I know).